# Some thing is not working

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to delete a content from a file 
so far I've reach this Idea of taking all the data that I don't to delete in another temp file then delete the the oldest and rename the temp 
here's my code :

```
string username;
                cout << "Enter The Employee you want to Remove : ";
                cin >> username;
                int i=0;
                string line1,line2,line3;
                fstream myfile;
                fstream temp;
                myfile.open("Data.txt");
                temp.open("temp.txt");
                if (myfile.is_open() || temp.is_open())
                {
                    while ( myfile >> line1 >> line2 >> line3 )
                    {
                        if(line1!="Employee" || username!=line2)
                        {
                            temp << line1 << endl << line2 << endl << line3 << endl;
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (line1=="Employee" && username==line2)
                        {   
                            i=1;
                        }
                    }
                    myfile.clear();
                    myfile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
                    myfile.close();
                    temp.close();
                    remove("Date.txt"); 
                    rename("temp.txt","Date.txt");
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        cout << "There is no Employee with The Name you Entered!" << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Employee data has been Deleted." << endl;
                    }
                }
```

I traced the code my self and it doesn't create the temp file !!
and could I use this technique to make the update?

Comment: Looks like when I Manually create the temp file it run

but it doesn't delete the oldest!!

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to read the code pasted like that... still, I'll give it a shot.

Why are you using

```
(myfile.is_open() || temp.is_open())
```

as condition? Shouldn't you verify that BOTH files are open, therefore being

```
(myfile.is_open() && temp.is_open())
```

?

I'm asking because probably your sw doesn't open the temporary file, possibly because you don't have writing rights on the folder from the OS, but still passes the OR conditional test and goes on.

But it's a wild guess.

Comment: I improved the post, sorry 4 that
Answering your question when I && it wont enter the if condition from the 1st place :/